# c# Newtonsoft deserialize a json string in al list of Objects

Tags: c#, json, web-services, serialization, deserialization

i have the following class

```
using System;

public class AppEventsClass
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

}
```

after calling a remote webservice i retrive the following json string:

```
{"d":"[title\":\"test\",\"description\":\"test desc\"},{\"title\":\"test2\",\"description\":\"desc test 2\"}]"}
```

after retriving that json string, how can i convert the string in a List<> of AppEventsClass with Newtonsoft?

I tried several solutions, but nothing that works fine for me.
for example this:

```
List<AppEventsClass> result = new List<AppEventsClass>();
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AppEventsClass>>(content).ToList();
```

and this is the .asmx that serializes the string:

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public string GetEvents()
    {
        using (mySQLDataContext ctx = new secondosensoSQLDataContext())
        {
            List<eventi> eventiList = ctx.eventi.ToList();
            List<AppEventsClass> eventiClassList = new List<AppEventsClass>();
            for (int i = 0; i < eventiList.Count; i++)
            {
                AppEventsClass a = new AppEventsClass();
                a.title = eventiList[i].titlolo_evento;
                a.description = eventiList[i].descrizione_evento;
                eventiClassList.Add(a);
            }
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventiClassList);
            return json;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please add some of what you tried so we can help solve those problems (Because a general deserialize json string of object list there were a few others only today already)

Comment: what solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: Your JSON formatting does not match your intended structure.  If you look carefully, you will find that it is simply a d property with a string that contains another object structure.  You need to think about how the json is getting serialized and how you intend to parse it apart.  None of that is apparent from your question.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will edit the question and post how i serialize the objects.

Comment: you are right @DavidL his json has this weird formatting with the d:

Comment: i edited the post and added the web method code that serializes the objects. @DavidL and Forlani , how can i serialize it with the right format?

Comment: @pasluc74669 what you've posted as a web service method doesn't match the json output your showing.  This question can't be properly answered with this disconnect.

Comment: I don't know the reason of the incorrrct format of the returned json.  If i call the webservice from browser, it seems to be correct (http://www.secondosenso.com/bat/appwebservice.asmx/GetEvents). But when i call the webservice from xamarin ios in c# it returns incorrect string..

Comment: @DavidL the output i posted is right the returned string of that method. Is it possible that the xamarin's Newtonsoft dll is different from the others, and have some bugs?

Answer (score 0):

1st issues seems that the response we retrieve is not formed correctly
Assumed that the json string is looking like the following:

```
 {"d":[{"title":"test","description":"test desc"},{"title":"test2","description":"desc test 2"}]}
```

The correct class for deserialization should look like this

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public D[] d { get; set; }
}

public class D
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

PS. Here is a working example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"d\":[{title:\"test\",description:\"test desc\"},{title:\"test2\",description:\"desc test 2\"}]}";
        var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
    }
}

public class Rootobject
{
    public D[] d { get; set; }
}

public class D
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mnimonic, How should i use it?

Comment: This is of course assuming that his json is correctly formatted, which it isn't.  So in the current state of the question, this doesn't answer it correctly.

Comment: Yes you are right i also had also a mistake on json!